# How to convert from Shapes to string, int, etc...?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a method of type Rectangle and it needs to return:

True:

- The name of rectangle passed to the method

Else:

- Width and height of that rectangle

This is the method: `public Rectangle ReturnStuff(Rectangle rect) {...stuff...};`

I've tried loads of stuff - for example (Rectangle) rect.ToString(); ConvertToString/Int()...
but nothing seems to work.

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Your question does not quite make sense.  A method does not have type it can have a return type.  How exactly are you trying to use this method?  Do you just want to print the information as a string or do you actually want the height and widths as values to use.  Why aren't you just using the properties on the Rectangle object?

Comment: Theirs no need to Cast a string to type Rectangle?? (I hope not..)

Comment: Rectangle ReturnStuff(Rectangle rect) {...stuff...}; (edited the original post). Forgot the method name, it's 3 am here :) It's not a constructor as mentioned below (mistake on my part). Basically, as i've mentioned, rectangle gets passed into a method, method does some stuff with it, and it needs to print out the name of the passed in rectangle, height and width. And to Nate, i hope there is a some sort of a cast?

Comment: What is the definition of Rectangle object.  Is it the standard .Net one or something else.  Also if you want to print out the name, height and width why are you returning a Rectangle object.  Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's an WPF application. I'm returning a Rectangle, cause that's how the method was assigned to me, i'd happily put a return type of string and be done with it, but can't do that :) Any ideas?

Comment: Since you are Declaring the return Type as Rectangle that is what you are stuck with... But all that information is part of the Rectangle that you passed in to the Method. All you need to do is to Return the Rectangle that was passed in, you can then get the values directly from the returned Rectangle.

Comment: What do you mean it was assigned to you?  Where are you trying to return information to.  Are you trying to print the information to the console or somewhere on a form from within the method?  You are saying print but you are not being clear about what that means.  This question is not a good question because people are guessing at what you really want and your comments are not helping.  Be more specific and provide information or you won't get the help you want.

Comment: Thanks for constructive criticism. By assigned i mean it was given to me like that (it was declared/formed/written like that before it got to me). There's a conditional statement inside the method, and if it's true it should return only the name of the rectangle, if not - only height and width. So i'm only interested in what it returns and how to accomplish that - as i wrote in the first post. My apologies if "print" confused someone - it really doesn't matter where the data will be printed out.

Comment: It sounds like your method definition is wrong.  What is consuming this function?  What is it expecting?  A rectangle object that only has a name or only the height or width populated.  Is this in some class that is doing something else with this information?  What determines the conditional inside the method?

Comment: What should be true? how can you pass a rectangle if it wasn't passed (false)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Rectangle (Rectangle rect) {};
```

That 'method' is a constructor.

Override the Object `ToString()` and implement it the way you want. Call it from another class.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "Rectangle";
}
```

Might want to return things like width height etc.

EDIT:

As you've changed your questionf from a Copy Constructor to a method of return type Rectangle I should probably clarify.

If you want the rectangle being passed in do this: (don't know why you had a semicolon on the end of the method...)

```
public void ManipulateRectangle(Rectangle rect) 
{
    rect.GetWidth(); //I don't know your rectangle class methods or data members.
    rect.GetHeight(); //etc.
}
```

Now if that's not what your looking for and instead you want to get a rectangle (by passing in a rectangle? I'm not sure why - unless your manipulating it in some way) you have to actually return an object of type Rectangle.

```
public Rectangle ManipulateRectangle(Rectangle rect) 
{
    var newRectangle = new Rectangle();
    newRectangle.SetWidth(rect.GetHeight()); //ex manipulation

    return newRectangle;
}
```

Just for refrence try to make your questions a little more specific :) It helps. Also names of methods, code that belongs in them, and what exactly you want to do should be included.

Comment: Erm That particular Constructor is called a Copy Constructor.

Comment: Thanks, bud, that's exactly what i was looking for (last example)! And yeah, i should and will make my questions more specific - first time here, so bear with me.

Comment: Glad I could help if it was the answer you can always click the green button below the arrows to give me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something looks odd with that method.

```
public Rectangle (Rectangle rect) {};
```

looks to me like a Constructor that's supposed to create one `Rectangle` from another `Rectangle`.

If you want to return the name of a rectangle you'd need something like:

```
public string RectangleName (Rectangle rect)
{
    return rect.ToString();
}
```

If the contructor is intended to make a copy of the passed-in rectangle then you need something like:

```
public Rectangle (Rectangle rect)
{
    this.name = rect.name;
    this.width = rect.width;
    this.height = rect.height;
}
```

Comment: You don't know the names of the data members.. lol

Comment: The question is then what are they?

Comment: @Nate - No, but it should give the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return three values (name, height and width) from one method.

The calling code would need to either use properties on the returned `Rectangle` if they're available, or the method could return a `Tuple<string,int,int>` containing the details.  The method could also use `out` parameters to return values to the calling code.

By far the best option in terms of design and readability is the first one - use properties on the returned 'Rectangle'.

So the calling code might look something like:

```
Rectangle rect1 = ???
Rectangle newRect = ReturnStuff(rect);
string name = newRect.ToString();
int width = newRect.Width;
int height = newRect.Height;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer bud, i've updated the original post to make what i'm trying to accomplish more clear (cond. statement). Any thoughts?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  You can't return two different type of data from a method based on a condition.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Can you provide the method code you have at the moment?